# Apache Camel timer route URI syntax

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel application with a timer route defined like this:

```
String timerURI = "timer:/MyApplication?period=5m";
```

I realized that the URI syntax is probably incorrect. The correct syntax as shown on the Apache Camel site should be:

```
String timerURI = timer://MyApplication?period=5m";
```

However, I noticed some strange behavior in the logs. In the first instance I show camel logging the URI as:

```
(route1) from(timer:///MyApplication?period=5m) --> bean[com.mypackage.....]
```

In the second instance, the log shows as:

```
(route1) from(timer://MyApplication?period=5m) --> bean[com.mypackage.....]
```

I tried a third option as

```
String timerURI = timer:MyApplication?period=5m";
```

and it showed in the logs as:

```
(route1) from(timer://MyApplication?period=5m) --> bean[com.mypackage.....]
```

When I defined the URI with a single /, as in the first case, I see an exception like this:

```
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: direct: due to: Expected scheme-specific part at index 7: direct:
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.normalizeEndpointUri(DefaultCamelContext.java:601)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:483)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.resolveEndpoint(ExchangeHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientListProcessor.resolveEndpoint(RecipientListProcessor.java:223)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientListProcessor.createProcessorExchangePairs(RecipientListProcessor.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:208)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:153)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:112
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 7: direct:
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2835)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3038)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
    at org.apache.camel.util.URISupport.normalizeUri(URISupport.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.normalizeEndpointUri(DefaultCamelContext.java:599)
    ... 51 more
```

So only with the first instance when I had single /, I saw this exception but the other two seem to be fine. Even stranger though, the error doesn't repeat very often. I never see it my local workspace but I saw it twice in my Dev test server and once in the Integration test server. Even after failing with this exception, it works in the next time when the timer runs after 5 minutes. Does anyone know how camel is interpreting these URLs and why it failed those few times?

Comment: Rishi - Could you please provide sample code ? I'm struggling to use from() API in my code and not sure how to configure camel-quartz in spring application-context.xml ?

Comment: @javaHelper: Router Class: 
`String timerURI = timer://MyApplication?period=5m";

@Autowired
private MyApplicationConsumerClass consumer;

from(timerUrl)
 .bean(consumer, "processQueueOnTimer('queueTimer')");
`

Consumer Class:
`@Component
public class MyApplicationConsumerClass {

 public void processQueueOnTimer(String queueTimer, Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  ...
  ...
 }
}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use no slashes, or use double slashes. eg

```
"timer:foo"
```

or

```
"timer://foo"
```

Then when having double slashes, then Camel regards this as no slashes, eg like http://foo.com, can be typed http:foo.com in the browser.

If you use 1 or 3 slashes, then that slash becomes part of the context-path for the component. Only a few components support a leading slash, such as the file/ftp components where a leading slash denotes the starting directory is `/foo` etc.

Comment: Is there any explanation why 1 slash works mostly except the few times? I would have expected errors all the time if it is not valid.