# How to create a custom Apache Camel Timer object

Tags: java, timer, apache-camel

Is there a way create a custom Apache Camel Timer as an object defined in java code rather than defining it as a dsl string pattern in the endpoint URI?

In the docs:  https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html  there is mention of this timer URI query param:

[image: timer (advanced) - To use a custom Timer]

but I haven't found examples of creating that "advanced" custom Timer.

Rather than specify a timer like this:

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60000").to("bean:myBean?method=someMethodName");
```

I would like to specify it as:

```
from("timer://foo?timer=com.MyCustomTimer").to("bean:myBean?method=someMethodName");
```

which would be accompanied by:

```
class MyCustomTimer implements TimerInterfaceICantFind{

    public MyCustomTimer(){
        setFixedRate(true);
        setPeriod(60000);   
    }
}
```

I'm wanting to do this so I can specify timer properties dynamically through java setters rather than substituting them into a string URI being constructed.

At the time of this writing, others have asked of Timer URI string syntax, but not of custom timers. Ex:

[Apache Camel timer route URI syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088154/apache-camel-timer-route-uri-syntax)

I saw in the camel source code, it looks like TimerComponent.getTimer() is returning a **java.util**.Timer

Would that imply that one needs to create the core java class: java.util.Timer - and set properties on it rather than using a camel version of a Timer object for a custom Timer?

[image: timer component]

Comment: A custom Timer is not the timer component but a `java.util.Timer` instance. Its very rarely needed so dont use it. You can configure the endpoint via Java code: TimerEndpoint te = new TimerEndpoint(); te.setXXX; te,setYYY; And then use te in your route from(te). Also mind that Camel 3.x comes with endpointdsl that allows to configure via fluent styling too: https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/master/examples/camel-example-cafe-endpointdsl

Comment: Defining the TimerEndpoint object with setters looks to throw an exception when used if it hasn't provided a constructed string uri: "endpointUri is not specified and org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerEndpoint does not implement createEndpointUri() to create a default value".  The endpoint dsl option in camel 3.x looks promising. My current requirement is the redhat fuse fabric 8 version of camel which looks to be depending on camel core 2.x still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom Timer that's referrred to in the camel docs is not a camel object but rather a **java.util.Timer** object.  It is lower level and not user friendly to work with manually in camel routes. It's not recommended to use.

You can't instantiate a camel **TimerEndpoint** object and use setters for its values without also manually specifying the endpoint string uri.

Without providing that uri - camel throws an exception with the message:

*"endpointUri is not specified and org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerEndpoint does not implement createEndpointUri() to create a default value".*

If using camel 3+  there is an endpoint dsl option available, **EndpointRouteBuilder**, that can create a timer endpoint through a builder:

```
RouteBuilder.addRoutes(camelContext, rb ->
    rb.from(timer("myTimer").fixedRate(true).period(500).advanced().synchronous(false))
            .delay(simple("${random(250,1000)}"))
            .process(this::newOrder)
            .to(direct("cafe")));
```

https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/master/examples/camel-example-cafe-endpointdsl/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/cafe/CafeRouteBuilder.java#L69

Answer (score -1):

If you insist to have the timer generated dynamically, perhaps you can take a look at Camel EndpointDSL which allows you to construct endpoints dynamically. Here is for [timer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-endpointdsl/src/generated/java/org/apache/camel/builder/endpoint/dsl/TimerEndpointBuilderFactory.java) and an [example](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/blob/master/examples/camel-example-cafe-endpointdsl/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/cafe/CafeRouteBuilder.java#L69) to use it.

Comment: Link does not works.