# Using Timer Component with Apache Camel and the period Query Parameter results in error: Error binding property (period=10) with name: period on bean:

Tags: java, timer, apache-camel, javabeans

I am using Apache Camel version 3.17.0.

I am trying to envoke a bean via the method pubMessage every 10ms.  When I add period=10 to the URI,

```
from("timer://firsttimer?period=10&exchangePattern=InOnly&repeatCount=100")
            .bean(SecondBean.class, "pubMessage");
```

I get the following error message:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[From[timer://firsttimer?period=10&exchangePatt... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: timer://firsttimer?exchangePattern=InOnly&period=10&repeatCount=100 due to: Error binding property (period=10) with name: period on bean: timer://firsttimer?exchangePattern=InOnly&period=10&repeatCount=100 with value: 10
```

When I remove **period=10** from the URI, everything works swell.  I should be able to put a period parameter per the Apache Camel [dox](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/timer-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_period)

This behavior extends back to at least 3.12.0.

Comment: Which Camel version are you using ?

Comment: The version is 3.17.0.

Comment: Did you already try with a higher value than 10 (for instance 1000 which is the default value). Remember the value is expressed in ms. And 10 ms is pretty quick.

Comment: Yes, regardless of the value for period it throws the same error.

Comment: You could try using `EndpointRouteBuilder` for the timer as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61273305/8996604

Comment: @Proksch Could you please provide the source code to replicate this issue. It would be helpful to raise a jira ticket for this. I am also facing the same problem and the solution provided requires considerable effort for a large project. The project currently uses Camel 2.24.3 and there is no issue in that for the same code.